# What will be the radius of the circle of the rolling coin? Gyroscope task

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes

I try to calculate the radius of the rolling coin. The task was found in physics book https://www.amazon.co.uk/General-Course-Physics-1-Mechanics/dp/5922102257 (only in Russian). But unfortunately my solution leads to the answer that differ from the answer provided in the book (by coefficient 3). I am trying to figure out if I made a mistake or there is a typo in the tutorial.

*Disk with radius **$r$** rolls skidless at an angular velocity **$w$** in an inclined position towards the ground. Thus, it makes a circle on the ground of radius **$R$**. The angle between the horizontal plane of the disc and the ground is **$\alpha$**. In addition $R>>r$. Find $R$.*

My solution:
[image]
variation of angular momentum:
$$\vec M=\dot {\vec L}$$
where $M$ - moment of force and $L$ - angular momentum of the disk.

There are three forсes affect the disk: (1) the force of gravity = mg downward, (2) earth pressure force that = - mg upwards and (3) force of static friction towards the center of the circle R. The first two forces create angular momentum $\vec M=[\vec {O_1O_2},\vec gravity]+[\vec {O_1O_3},\vec{earth pressure}]=[\vec{O_1O_2},\vec{mg}]−[\vec{O_1O_3},\vec{mg}]=-[\vec r,\vec{mg}]=mgr\,cos(\alpha)$

$$mgr\,cos(\alpha)=[\vec \Omega \vec L]$$ where $m$ is a weight of the disc and  $\Omega$ - angular velocity related to the movement of the disk around the circle.
$$\Omega R=wr $$
$$\Omega =wr/R $$
$$\vec L=I_\parallel \vec{w_\parallel}+I_\bot \vec{w_\bot}$$ where $I_\parallel$ is the moment of inertia passing through the center of the disk along the axis of symmetry of the disk, $I_\bot$ is the moment of inertia passing perpendicular to the axis of symmetry of the disk. $\vec w_\parallel$ and $\vec w_\bot$ are components of the vector $\vec w$ passing along the axis of symmetry of the disk and perpendicular.

$w_\parallel\approx w\sqrt{1-r^2/R^2}$

The fact that $R>>r$ leads to the $w_\parallel\approx w$:
$$\vec L=I_\parallel \vec{w_\parallel}+I_\bot \vec{w_\bot} \approx I_\parallel \vec{w}$$

$$I_\parallel=mr^2/2$$
$$[\vec \Omega \vec L]=\Omega L \, sin(\alpha)$$
Thus:
$$R=\frac{w^2r^2}{2g}tg(\alpha)$$

But in the book where i found this task the answer is $R=\frac{3w^2r^2}{2g}tg(\alpha)$
I think there is a mistake in the book. It is not clear where the coefficient three came from.
Can anyone check?

Comment: Shouldn't the $R>>r$ fact be used somewhere? @Alexey

Comment: @Lelouch I think *R* >> r *is* used. I think the derviation is already using the approximation that is valid only when $\Omega$ is much smaller than $\omega$. In order for  $\Omega$ to be be much smaller than $\omega$: *R* must be much larger than *r*.

Comment: @Lelouch I add additional point where R>>r is used

Comment: Incidentally, the setup described in the task is unphysical. A rolling disk, encountering bumps, will *still* tend to proceed in a straight line. Imagine, say, a rolling coin, rolling straight, but starting to lean, say to the right. The *motion* of starting to lean to the right gives rise to *turn* to the right, which has the effect of bringing the contact point back underneath the center of mass. Thus the rolling coin is robust in tendency to roll along a straight line. Of course, the *intention* of the task was to treat the calculation as if it is the same case as gyroscopic precession.

Comment: @Cleonis The rolling coin is initially in an inclined position towards the ground. There are three forсes affect coin: (1) the force of gravity = mg downward, (2) earth pressure force that = - mg upwards and (3) force of static friction towards the center of the circle R. The first two forces create angular momentum $M=[O_1 O_2, mg] - [O_1 O_3, mg]=[r, mg] $

Comment: @Cleonis The setup described in the task is absolutely physical.
The question is an interesting problem of dynamics of a rigid body,  
especially if solved (hard work!) without the restriction R >> r.
In the simple case R >> r the solution of the book is not wrong,
but unfortunately the question was unexpectedly closed.

Comment: @Pangloss The question was market as off-topic. I am trying to reopen it. Could you please give me a hint about the correct way.

Comment: @Pangloss I retract my statement as to whether the case is physical. I took a coin, tried to roll it, most of the times the coin rolled in a fairly straight line, a couple of times hitting a bump made the rolling coin veer into what appeared to be motion along a circle with fairly constant radius. I didn't see a full circle, presumably due to losing velocity to friction. So I retract; I cannot exclude the possibility that in the frictionless (yet skidless) case the disk can roll along a circle.

Comment: @Pangloss Refuting my expectation: this numerical simulation does give motion along a circle as a solution. https://rotations.berkeley.edu/the-rolling-disk/

Comment: @Cleonis Thank you a lot for the provided link where it is simulated. It is now clear. I understand my mistake - I forget about angular momentum of static friction force.Very good numerical simulation.